# Accessing files from other filesystems along with hdfs files in a hadoop mapreduce application

Tags: java, hadoop

I know that we can call a map-reduce job from a normal java application. Now the map-reduce jobs in my case has to deal with files on hdfs and also files on other filesystem. Is it possible in hadoop that we can access files from other file system while simultaneously using the files on hdfs. Is that possible ?

So basically my intention is that I have one large file which I want to put it in HDFS for parallel computing and then compare the blocks of this file with some other files(which I do not want to put in HDFS coz they need to be accessed as full length file at once.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Your non-hdfs files have to be available from each tasktracker I guess. Like a network share.

Comment: Can you let me know how do we do that, I have googled that I found no example where we can deal with non-hdfs file in hadoop. Thank you so much for the response

Comment: If your concern is that your files are getting split, you should put them on HDFS but use a subclass of [FileInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html) that does not split them when you launch your MapReduce job.

Comment: So what I want to do is that the input to a map will be chunk of a big file, and the contents of this file will be compared against the files that I plan on keeping it non-hdfs file system. Your answer made me think of another question, can I directly access a file in hdfs in the map function and the file will not be split ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [distributed cache](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/mapred_tutorial.html#DistributedCache) to distribute the files to your mappers, they can open and read the files in their `configure()` method (don't read them in `map()` as it will be called many times.)

**edit**

In order to access file from the local filesystem in your map reduce job, you can add those files to the distributed cache when you setup your job configuration.

```
JobConf job = new JobConf();
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/myapp/lookup.dat#lookup.dat"), job);
```

The MapReduce framework will make sure those files are accessible by your mappers.

```
public void configure(JobConf job) {
    // Get the cached archives/files
    Path[] localFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(job);

    // open, read and store for use in the map phase.
}
```

and remove the files when your job is done.

Comment: I think I did not frame my question clear. I want to have one file in HDFS and the other three files in a normal file system and access the files in normal file system from the map-reduce app.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to access non-HDFS file system from mapper/reducer tasks just like any other tasks. One thing to note is that if there a are say 1K mappers and each of them will try to open the non-HDFS file, this might lead to a bottle neck based on the type of the external file system. The same is applicable with mappers pulling data from a database also.

Comment: Thank you so much. That is right, if I try to do that it will certainly lead to a bottle neck. Do you have any suggestions. As far a s my thinking goes I think it would be better to store all these in hdfs and feed the large file as input and when I access a file from the mapper function, Can i access the whole file ?

Comment: You can put both the files in HDFS. If you think that too many maps/reducers are accessing the file in HDFS for reading, then the replication factor for the file can be increased appropriately. The problem can't be addressed without knowing the requirements in detail.

Comment: Please correct me, but I understood that a map reduce job may only have one inputformat. But the large file has to be split and the small ones don't which would require two inputformats.